Sum one column while row collapsed
My report looks like this collapsed:

And when expanded:

So what I need to do is have the No of high BrAC column sum the values while it's collapsed, so the first screenshot, I need to have a value of 8 rather than blank.
This is my row group:

And the No of high BrAC column:

What am I missing to achieve the desired result?

Whatbis the current expression on your column Case Number? Your screenshots suggest that there isn't one. What's wrong with the Sum function?

Case Number is simply set with a visibility filter, triggered by account_no collapse/expand. I've blocked it out in the screenshot due to it being sensitive info. The SUM function just isn't working, not sure how else to describe it. I expand and see the 1's, but collapsed, it's blank, per the screenshot. For further clarity, all columns to the right of account_no have the visibility filter just as Case Number does.

"Not working" doesn't tell us anything. And blocking out the sample data and not telling us the expected results make is impossible for us to tell you anything.

Ok, I think there's a misunderstanding. All I am wanting to see is the No of high BrAC summed while collapsed. So currently, it is blank, per the first screenshot. Since there are 8 rows, instead of it being blank, I want to see a value of 8. When I expand, I see the 8 rows, each with a value of 1, which is fine. I don't need any aggregation on any other column, they are behaving just fine.

Ahh, I thought you were highlighting the Case Number column, due to the large box surrounding it, and stating that's where you want the value.

I realize how that could be visually confusing, I should have highlighted the correct column.

If you want a value for the uncollapse value, you need an additional row inside the group; SSRS doesn't support rows changing values when you expand the group at the aggregate level.

Ok, I think that's probably the resolution to my inquiry. That SSRS doesn't actually support what I'm trying to do. Thanks for the confirmation!

You should have a group at account level the the detail group below it. The account level group will use the SUM() expression and the detail rows will just have the field values. Set the details rowgroup visibility to be based on the account no (from the account row group). The only issue is that the account group with the sum will be present even when you expand
